# Static Files issue between local environment and aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

When deploying to AWS, I am having issues getting static files to load from different apps, also the admin styling is lost in AWS.

Below what I list for locally is how it was working previously, then below that are the changes I made to get it to work in aws, though now some of the .css files are loading empty on my local environment when running it as it should be for AWS.

Also if I try and leave STATICFILES_DIRS and have STATIC_ROOT, I get an error.

When running locally I need settings.py to contain:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Reporting/static/Reporting"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Organization/static/Organization")
]
```

When running in aws I need

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static") # ADDED for AWS
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

ebextentions:

```
02_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is responsible for serving static files on your AWS deployment?

Comment: For right now the static files are being collected on the same EC2 instance as django. This is a dev site in aws for now but before creating prod I will most likely be pointing them to an S3 bucket.

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. What is responsible for serving them from that location?